# What does a rough analysis on this piece give?

Tags: classical-music, concert

I would like some insight into what could be said of this piece in regards to anything that is generally spoken of a piece when it is being analyzed or critiqued.

It is called [El Viaje Imaginario by Federico Ibarra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPG52v0vUU8)  and I like it quite a lot. I am not asking for an indepth analysis but just something that could point me in the right direction so I could appreciate it better.

So far all I can seem to discern is that it is probably in minor key, and its tempo oscillates between slow and fast. The piano and clarinet mainly play arpeggios instead of chords.

Comment: Hi Ayudh. Can you tell us what have you found until now... maybe it could help us to not redo again the job you already done.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.  There are innumerable different ways to analyze a song.  Are you looking for similar music?  The repetitive elements remind me a bit of Philip Glass, but the overall feel is quite different --much more "organic" than his music typically is.

Comment: If you want to talk about actual analysis(harmonic, motif, form), it's a much better fit on [Music SE](http://music.stackexchange.com/) than here. If you want to talk about analyzing for genre instead it's much better here.